# Spring Integration SftpSession will rmdir delete a non-empty directory?

Tags: spring-integration

The javadoc is pretty sparse on this. If I have

```
sftp = sftpFactory.getSession();
sftp.rmdir(directory);
```

where "directory" is non-empty, would I expect it to delete the directory and all its contents?

Additionally, will `sftp.rename(file, newfile)` overwrite by default?

If documentation on this exists that I've just missed, I apologize and would be grateful for a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such operations are a function of the remote filesystem, not the sftp client.

Typically,

- No; the directory won't be deleted.
- No; the rename will fail.